# Dynamically register directive at runtime

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-module

Normally, directives are registered on a module by using the `directive` method:

```
.directive('MyDirective', function (MyDep) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }
    }
});
```

However, what if I dynamically want to register directives during runtime? For example, say a user pulls the following data from the server:

```
{
    directives: {
        dir1: {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div></div>',
        },
        dir2: {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div></div>',
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can take this data use it to dynamically register new directives for my app? If successful, I should then be able to dynamically generate and `$compile` HTML which depends on them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a subset of the "lazy loading Angular artifacts" problem (I have explored [here](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) and there exist other resources too). An idea is to use a `config` function to "steal" the `$compileProvider` ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider)) and then call `$compileProvider.directive(...)` on demand, based on your data.

A rough sketch of the idea is:

```
var cachedCompileProvider;
angular.module(...).config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
    cachedCompileProvider = $compileProvider;
});
```

And then (e.g. from inside someplace that has access to `$http`):

```
$http.get(...).then(function(response) {
    angular.forEach(response.data.directives, function(dirDefinition, dirName) {
        cachedCompileProvider.directive(dirName, dirDefinition);
    });
});
```

(Of course you cannot receive controller functions from a JSON response like the above, you will have to use other techniques - but hopefully you get the idea.)

Comment: Thanks, this indeed looks like it could be it. I corrected the invalid JSON in my question (copy-paste does strange things to the brain), but will the compiler still let me add a controller by, on the client side, running something like `dirDefinition.controller = function($scope) { /... };`?

Comment: Yes, of course, the `dirDefinition` is a standard directive definition object with controllers, link functions etc. It's just that you cannot get it from JSON due to the reasonable limitations of that format. You *can*, however, get a text response, `eval` it, and use it as a directive definition if you like (and feel comfortable with `eval`).

Comment: Nice, but look this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/nUOsDVq0eDxqyzkKEdm4) if you first show list and then attempt  to register directive  the already compiled template does not recompile, while if you first register directive then you see it in action when showing list

Comment: Thanks for the lead , made my life easier .